# Download the Contents of a PHP Variable to a File

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this data that I get from my MySQL table and I've stored it in a variable called $arr.
I've json_encoded it into a $json variable:

```
$arr = array();
    while ($blah = mysqli_fetch_assoc(...)) {
          $arr[key] = value;
    }
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

The thing that I'm trying to do is to download the contents of just the $json variable into a .json file without saving it on the server. But when I try to do that using

```
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file.'');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        echo $json;
```

(where $file is a generated name for the downloaded file) I get something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
          ....
    </head>
    <body>

<a ...>...</a>{"field":"value","field2":"Ð˜Ð·Ð²ÐµÑÑ‚Ð¸Ñ","field3":"ÐÐžÐ’", ...} </body></html>
```

or the whole .php file content in other words... And as you can see, the encoding is all messed up.

Can you help me identify the problem and possibly give me any ideas on how to fix it.

Any help would be really appreciated : ]

Comment: How can you create a file without saving it on the server?

Comment: Do you output already data earlier / do you include the php file in a template? Be sure that no output is sent

Comment: Well I mean just get the contents of the variable and write them to a file. Like - when the user clicks Download, he gets a prompt to download a .json file with the contents of variable $json. I hope you understand.

Comment: I'm using PHP but I want the downloaded file to have a .json extension.

Comment: do you use a framework? sh*t like Drupal wraps your content many times. Perhaps what you're suffering is a layout wrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because you are outputting your HTML before the `echo $json` line.
There should be nothing printing to the page before a header() function. I usually have a separate PHP file (away from the template of a page) to build downloadable files.

Comment: Yep, that works as a charm... I guess the problem was I didn't quite understand what was going on. Thank you very much : ]

Answer (score 0):

To build on thePav's answer.

You cant have anything before your header declarations, I.E. if you try to redirect a page using header('location: something.html'); it wont work if you have echoed anything before  it.

I will generally set up a "file fetcher" php file that I can pass an ID hash to then link that php file on my download links.

For instance:

```
<a href="filegrabber.php?id=123345">Click here to download</a>
```

Also, you may want to read through the docs for the header function, theres a lot of useful info there.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Thank you a lot too. I'll keep that in mind for future projects. : ]